# Mock a formset save_formset method django forms?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am new to writing tests and wanted to know the right approach on how I can mock a ModelAdmin save_formset functionality. Basically, I don't want to create a formset and want to mock the value of the formset.forms and pass it to the function so that it just tests the important part of the save_formset function. However, at the end of the function it still tries to call the ModelAdmin formset.save() method and that's where I get a NoneType attribute because in reality I am not passing an actual formset to the function. This is what I tried so far
**admin.py**

```
 def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        forms = self.get_formset_forms(formset)
        for f in forms:
            obj = f.instance
            if not hasattr(obj, "creator"):
                obj.creator = request.user
        formset.save()


    def get_formset_forms(self,formset):
        return formset.forms
```

tests.py

```
  @patch("core.apps.survey.admin.SurveyAdmin.get_formset_forms")
        def test_save_formset(self,mock_get_formset_forms,mock_formset_save):
            user = mixer.blend(User)
            mock_get_formset_forms.return_value = [{'instance':{'iss':user}}]
            mock_formset_save.return_value=1
            site = AdminSite()
            survey_admin = admin.SurveyResponseAdmin(Survey, site)
            survey_admin.save_formset(request=None, form=None, formset=None, change=None)
```

error log

```
 survey_admin.save_formset(request=None, form=None, formset=None, change=None)

core/apps/survey/tests/test_admin.py:56: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <core.apps.survey.admin.SurveyResponseAdmin object at 0x7f4ed5feadc0>, request = None, form = None, formset = None, change = None

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        """
        Given an inline formset save it to the database.
        """
>       formset.save()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```